# Why didn't my name show up when I marked a question duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

Earlier today, I marked a question on Stack Overflow as a duplicate. Then I waited about 5-10 minutes and it showed 5 people. However, my name wasn't included.

I also remember that the question that was linked on top was the same question that I selected.

Now I'm not trying to ask for the "spotlight" but I just want to know how does this naming system work? Do they go in order or do they go by reputation?

Comment: Asked on Meta SO: [I was not included in *marked as duplicate by*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373730/4642212).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Whenever a question is put on hold, the 5 people (less if a diamond moderator is involved) you see are the people who actually cast a vote to close.

In your case, you flagged the question instead, which means you are not one of the five, and hence are not shown.

As for the order in which names appear, it is in order of when each user cast a vote to close. (Here's an old [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110272/what-is-the-rationale-for-not-randomizing-the-list-of-close-voters) that explicitly mentions the order, thanks to @MartijnPieters for digging it out.)

For more info on closing, there's the help center [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) on casting close votes (as already mentioned by @jmort253), and also [What is a "closed", “on hold”, or "duplicate" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question).

(Note that while it's true that you need 3000 reputation to cast close/reopen votes on general questions, you gain the ability to do so on your own questions at 250 reputation.)

Comment: As for the order in which names appear, my impression was that it goes in order of when the vote is cast. I'll update this into the answer once I find out for sure.

Comment: You are correct about the order, yes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is there a link that says for sure? I've been hunting around for it, but haven't found it yet. Will keep looking for now.

Comment: Here is one by Anna: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101746/how-does-the-revisions-view-decide-whether-to-display-the-post-closed-notice-giv/101748#101748

Comment: Much better one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110272/what-is-the-rationale-for-not-randomizing-the-list-of-close-voters

Comment: @MartijnPieters Excellent! Linked to that in my answer; thanks for the help!

Answer (score 9):

You only have 491 reputation on Stack Overflow. At that level of reputation, you can, and are encouraged, to participate in bringing exceptional circumstances to the attention of moderators and reviewers by flagging the question.

However, the privilege to actually make the decision to close the question doesn't come until you hit 3000 reputation.  5 users with 3000 reputation can close or reopen a question, whereas flaggers merely bring something to the attention of moderators.

For more about how voting to close works, please see [The Help Center's Page on Close Voting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).  Also, check out the entire list of [Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

You have less than 3000 rep, so you can only flag for closure, not vote to close. That requires 3K rep or more.

Your name only shows up if you actually *vote* to close